# The probability for a team to win the cup in a championship. A simplified case.

Tags: probability

Hypotesys: For each two national football teams $i$ and $j$ that play against each other the probability of victory for $i$ is defined as:

${{p}_{i}}=\frac{{{N}_{i}}}{{{N}_{i}}+{{N}_{j}}}$,

where $N$ is the population of the country (the larger the state the more talents can be found and the stronger the team).

There are initially ${{2}^{n}}$ countries and after each round only ${{2}^{n-1}}$ remain. Immediately before each phase of the competition the pairs of teams that will play against each other are randomly selected.

**Question**: What is the probability ${{p}_{i,1}}$  with which the country $i$ of population $N_i$ win the cup?

I have heard repeatedly the answer: ${{p}_{i,1}}=\frac{{{N}_{i}}}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^n}{{{N}_{k}}}}$ which satisfy the condition $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^n}{{{p}_{k,1}}}=1$ (the cup is always won by one state) but I have no demonstration for this result.

Another answer would be:

${{p}_{i,1}}={{\left( \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1,k\ne i}^{{{2}^{n}}}{\frac{{{N}_{i}}}{{{N}_{i}}+{{N}_{k}}}}}{{{2}^n-1}} \right)}^{n}}$,

a formula that has some logic behind it but does not satisfy the condition $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^n}{{{p}_{k,1}}}=1$.

UPDATE

Using the answers I have received i finally found the formula:

${{p}_{1}}\left( W \right)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{N1}{N1+N2}\left( \frac{N1}{N1+N3}\frac{N3}{N3+N4}+\frac{N1}{N1+N4}\frac{N4}{N3+N4} \right)+\frac{1}{3}\frac{N1}{N1+N3}\left( \frac{N1}{N1+N2}\frac{N2}{N2+N4}+\frac{N1}{N1+N4}\frac{N4}{N2+N4} \right)+\frac{1}{3}\frac{N1}{N1+N4}\left( \frac{N1}{N1+N2}\frac{N2}{N2+N3}+\frac{N1}{N1+N3}\frac{N3}{N2+N3} \right)$

which is the probability of a country to win the cup out of a group of 4 states.

I am still looking for the general formula or an algorithm that can be applied also to 8, 16, 32, etc. countries.

Comment: Your first suggested answer looks wrong to me: if $n=4$ and the populations are $1,2,3,4$ millions then the probabilities of winning seem to be $\dfrac{1207}{18900}, \dfrac{3508}{18900}, \dfrac{5913}{18900}, \dfrac{8272}{18900}$, i.e. about $0.06386243, 0.18560847, 0.31285714, 0.43767196$, not $0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4$.  What makes you think there is a simple answer?

Comment: n=4 means 16 countries not 4.

Comment: OK: then I meant $n=2$

Comment: You might be right. How did you reason? Hoe did you get the probabilities you calculated.

Comment: There are in effect $24$ possible sets of results and it is not hard to work out the probabilities

Comment: I have found those 24 cases but I have no clue how to get your probabilities. I still get the sum of the four probabilities larger than 1 using I guess false premises.